# Signal coherence/correlation vs quantum coherence

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator, correlation-functions, decoherence, coherence

In general, I understand a signal $s(t) \in \mathbb{C}$ is called "coherent" when it has a large autocorrelation function. A pair of different signals $s(t)$, $r(t)$ can also be "coherent" if their cross-correlation is large (this can be made precise). I also understand a bit of the density matrix formalism $\rho$ in quantum mechanics and what is meant by quantum coherence.

However, I fail to see a clear mathematical connection between the two, beyond some phenomenological similarities when talking about "waves". Could anyone shed some light on it?